# JfreeChart show failed message on specific Bar or Point

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am trying to generate Timeseries and Bar graph for average time taken by a build. If it takes less than certain amount of time i am assuming it as failed build.I want to show a failed message on specific bar or point in graph. Anyone having any idea how to do that.
Here is my graph data

```
2014-05-03 1076
2014-05-04 1950
2014-05-05 1980
2014-05-06 10 (failed build, this bar or point should be flaged)
```

Comment: Have you tried one of the `org.jfree.chart.annotations`?

Comment: Nope, trying to explore this. Any example ?

Comment: You might look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20org.jfree.chart.annotations) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info).